# Cloud Platform Create Project error

Tags: google-cloud-platform

New user to GCP. I'm set up as administrator of all groups, have created the billing and am up to Step 5 of Set up Your Foundation.

- Enabled GSuite/Workspace Apps > Additional Google services: Google
  Cloud Platform, Google Developers.
- In Manage Resources (step 5), my org is checked and I'm listed in Permissions as the Org Admin and Project Creator.

When I click Create Project, I keep getting the error message:

> "Create Project:
>
> Google Cloud Platform service has been disabled. Please contact your
> administrator to turn the service on in the Google Workspace Admin
> console."

As noted above, I am the admin and the service is enabled. Do I have the correct service? How can I create my project?

Can someone please help me? Thank you soooo much!

Answer (score 0):

### I can't create a new project in Google Cloud Platform, says GCP service has been disabled

Have managed to find the setting, if anyone else has the same trouble finding them:

1. From Admin console
2. Search for 'Additional Google Services'
3. Select Additional Google Services App Settings
4. Enable 'Google Cloud Platform'

[**Check this reference for more details**](https://support.google.com/accounts/thread/9670625/i-can-t-create-a-new-project-in-google-cloud-platform-says-gcp-service-has-been-disabled?hl=en)

Comment: Just as a note, this doesn't seem to work for me (and I enabled it days ago, so it's not the 'wait 24 hours' thing).  I suspect it's because the accounts (admin/user) were part of the old Google Apps thing that they abandoned.  I've not found a solution yet.